# Scraping from applications other than browsers on Debian Jessie

Tags: text-processing, desktop-environment

I'm thinking of building an automated trading system.
I think there's probably no services supplying informations of order book and top of book in the txt format.

So I have to do scraping.

I want to know whether one can extract text data programmatically and automatically from applications other than browsers.

I want to get the output file `~/Desktop/foo.txt`.
So for example, when many lines more than 100 in terminal are scrolling,
is it possible to do scraping the terminal output without using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>/<kbd>v</kbd>] neither [Edit & Copy]?

For second example, when many slides are appearing in the slide show mode of Libre Office Impress, is it possible to do scraping all the text data?

I want to know the method applicable to all other applications.
Is there such a method other than screenshot & OCR?
What package offers such a function?

Comment: Err what do you want to do exactly? With terminal you can pipe the output of the command to various things (including the clipboard) anyway...

Comment: Do you want to scrape programmatically, or using a mouse, cursor, or something manually?

Comment: @Wilf and roaima: Sorry I've edited. I want to do scraping all the text output of the terminal emulator like 
[$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://ftp.jp.debian.org jessie InRelease Hit http://ftp.jp.debian.org jessie Release.gpg .....]
I want to get a txt file including [$ sudo apt-get update] in this example.

Comment: Should be easy enough for a command output - a basic redirection of everything would be `sudo apt-get update > file 2>&1` - you could also copy the output to a file (helps with interactive stuff),  also possible to to use `xclip` for the clipboard - for the presentation you would need something that would either select n copy or just takes apart the presentation file. I would add a answer but this has been closed - also I would suggest *detailing* the bit about the presentation text in a separate question would be better.

Comment: @Wilf: I apologize for my poor explanation. Please read the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid a tool like this can't exist. Your idea is basically to log every piece of text written by every application into a log file. This would require a common system interface for all applications, so you could set a hook for that logging.

But applications are free to use any library to do the rendering or implement their own rendering, do it on the GPU or just copy bitmaps. In this case the only common interface to all applications is windowing system (like `X`), seeing nothing but changing pixels that would really need to be OCR'ed permanently -- an impossible thing to do.

What you could do to get closest to your requirement is to modify the FreeType library to log each piece of text rendered by FreeType. This should cover a lot of linux application, but surely not all. And please expect it to produce a lot of chaotic output when spaces are not passed to FreeType, windows are scrolled upward and several applications are running synchronously.